# How to change background color of a link in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation

[image]

How to change vertical menu background color on hover in Magento 2
I want like this.

Answer (score 0):

Right click and inspect the element. Use chrome developer or your browsers equivalent. Look in the box on the far right. You'll see :hov, click on it and you'll be able to select the css hover/focus/active/visited styles. Then just copy the element + :hover and add your style to your custom.css file.

`<vendor>/<theme>/web/css/custom.css(or whatever you call your css file)`

Comment: I tried that but it's not useful

Comment: Can you see what element the style is being applied to in Firebug?

Comment: I tried all ways but still not getting

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `<li class="category-menu dropdown"></li>`  Generally background-color is applied there.

Comment: I tried that also.